# Finding the Average from a list of numbers in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, average

This is my first attempt at java problem I have been given as part of my Programming assignment.

I must make a program which calculates the average of a list of numbers that a user enters. the data enty should be terminated when 0 is entered. my problem is with this "ALL NEGATIVE NUMBERS SHOULD BE IGNORED"

for some reason the following code does not work, when I enter a negative number it should be ignored but for some reason it terminates the data enty

```
import java.util.*;

class Task_8
  {
public static void main()
  {

    Scanner inputLine = new Scanner(System.in);

    float row, numberentered, numbersum = 0, negativenumber = 0;
    double result, count = 0;


    System.out.println ("Welcome to Task 8 of 10 of my Programming Assignment... Nearly There!");
    System.out.println ("_____________________________________________________________________");
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Enter as many numbers as you like and this program will tell you the arithmatic mean");
    System.out.println ("Terminate data entry by entering 0");


   do{

       System.out.print ("Please enter a number: ");
        numberentered = inputLine.nextInt();

        count++;

        if (numberentered < 0)
        {
            numberentered  = negativenumber;   
        }

        numbersum = ( numberentered + numbersum ) - negativenumber;

    }

  while  ( numberentered !=0 );

     result = numbersum/count;
     System.out.println ();
     System.out.println ("*************************************");
     System.out.println ();
     System.out.println ("The sum of all of the numbers you entered is " +numbersum);
     System.out.println ("You entered " + count + " numbers");
     System.out.println ("The Average/mean of the numbers that you entered is " + result);


    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("*************************************");

  }
}
```

any Ideas guys?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable *negativenumber* always has the value zero. When you set *numberentered* to *negativenumber* the "while" condition is met, and the loop exits. A better strategy would be to us "continue" to skip the rest of the loop body when a negative number was entered.

Comment: Thank you very much, have only been learning this for a few days so really struggling. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you want to ignore the negative number, then don't include it in your calculation.  Instead do something like:

```
if (numberentered > 0)
{
   numbersum += numberentered;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Examine the following block of code:

```
if (numberentered < 0)
{
    numberentered  = negativenumber;   
}
```

What this is doing is setting `numberentered` to 0.  Then, at the end of your do-while loop, you have this:

```
while(numberentered != 0);
```

So, whenever the user types in a negative number, you set `numberentered` to zero.  When you reach the end of the loop, `numberentered != 0` is false, so the loop exits.

The simpler solution, and something more akin to what you will learn to do on a regular basis in the future, is to simply check the value of the number in an if statement and then add it or not based on its value.

```
if(numberentered > 0)
    numbersum += numberentered;
```

This is clean, concise, and removes the need for the `negativenumber` variable which is superfluous and could be confusing.  If you were looking at this code a year from now, would you remember what `negativenumber` meant, or why it was set to zero?  Write your code as if somebody else will have to read it and understand it.  Your professors will, and, in the future, your colleagues will.

On another note, you are reading in integers (with `inputLine.nextInt()`) but storing them in a `float`.  You've also declared `count` as a `double`.  You most likely will want to declare `count`, `numberentered`, and `numbersum` as an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a value other than 0 (in initialization) to `negativenumber`, then you do

```
if (numberentered < 0)
{
    numberentered  = negativenumber;   
}
```

and the do...while-loop terminates because `numberentered` is 0.